# How to add a block (phtml) into specified product view (bundle)

Tags: magento

I want to add a custom block into a bundle product type only.
That mean the custom block only shows when it is a bundle product.

```html
<catalog_product_view>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle translate="label">
         <reference name="content">
            <reference name="product.info.media.after">
                <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="module_block" as="other" template="companyname/module/selection.phtml"/>
            </reference>
        </reference>
        </PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle> 
</catalog_product_view>
```

I try to use `<product type_bundle>` in my module `layout xml`, but it does not work, can every one help?

Comment: have you call a childhtml in product page for your block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing this the right way, but your XML is a bit wrong. The `PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle` should be at the top level:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
         <reference name="content">
            <reference name="product.info.media.after">
                <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="module_block" as="other" template="companyname/module/selection.phtml"/>
            </reference>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
</layout>
```

You also may be able to leave the "content" reference out:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
        <reference name="product.info.media.after">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="module_block" as="other" template="companyname/module/selection.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
</layout>
```

**EDIT:** made layout snippets more clear by mocking the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

All blocks inside "content" block are automatically outputted. You can either add you custom block directly inside "content", like this:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="module_block" as="other" template="companyname/module/selection.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Also, as I can see `product.info.media.after` is `core/text_list`, which means that it should output underlaying blocks automatically.

Possible you don't have that template. If that is the situation, you will get a notice in `var/log/system.log` or `var/log/exception.log`

Also, try to change `as="other"` to something more unique (since you are maybe using duplicated name for a block).

Comment: thanks but how can i specific to one product type? such as Downloadable, or Bundle product?